# Can Anyone Figure Out this CSS Alignment Issue?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a search textbox and two image buttons on a page I created with ASP.NET.

When I look at the page with either IE8, Google Chrome or Opera, the textbox does not align with the two image buttons. The buttons appear higher than the textbox and I can't tell why.

Here is the key markup:

```
<div id=searchbar>
    <div id=Panel1
        onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'btnSearch')">
        <input id=txtSearch type=text name=ctl00$txtSearch>
        <input id=btnSearch title=Search src="Test_files/search.png"
            type=image name=ctl00$btnSearch>
        <input id=btnAdvanced title="Advanced Search" src="Test_files/adv.png"
            type=image name=ctl00$btnAdvanced>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I realize there are a few strange things here such as no quotes around the ids. But there **ARE** quotes around them in my source. The above snippet is from saving the content from IE and it made a number of changes to the markup.

I also posted the same code at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Test/Test.htm if anyone would be willing to take a look. The issue is with the search controls to the right of the black bar near the top.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
vertical-align:text-bottom;
```

on the elements that are too high.  It's a common problem.  You can try out other options for that CSS property too if that isn't quite right.  Have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Comment: You need to add this to all three of the elements, but this works.

Comment: I actually had tried this but I added it to the containing <div>. Removing it from the div and adding it to the textbox and two images did the trick. Although I'm entirely sure why.

Comment: Personally, for common things like this I create classes that have just one or two properties then use multiple classes on my elements.  So I have classes for things like float:left/right and other common properties that you frequently need to use.  I find it actually makes html more readable when you have a set of classes on an element like "left half-width bordered"

Comment: @Jonathan Wood This doesn't inherit to children.  It has to be applied to the element you want aligned specifically.  But you can do div#Panel1 input{vertical-align:text-bottom;} to apply it to all the inputs in the div in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 2):

just add

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

to the the input tags css and that should solve the issue